# What is locale property in qml controle ? How to use it?

Tags: qt, properties, qml

I want to be familiar with locale property of qml controle component , i understand that it is used for Qlocale methods but i dont find any good example

Comment: And what is not clear about the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#locale-prop)? It formats the numbers

Comment: How to set this locale property in qml  and how to change it runtime ?

Comment: you can call (setDefault(...))[https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#setDefault] from C++. Normally you don't have to explicitly set it for qml controls, as it uses the locale from the parent, which boils down to the default if never touched. If you do want to set it for a specific control you can use `locale: Qt.locale("de_DE")`

Comment: thanks for your very informative answer but can u share one example in which we we set locale via c++ and use it in qml?

Comment: Please tell me what use-case you are looking for, then I can post an answer. Are you looking for general locale setting or specific locale for one control? (You should probably edit your question as it is in general profit)

Comment: i am looking for use-case in someone sets locale of qml button via c++ and uses it in its text and also change its whenever possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to change the locale that is used on a specific Control, you can export a string property on a C++ model:

```
class MyModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString editLocale MEMBER editLocale_) //more elaborate variants are possible

    private:
        QString editLocale_;
}
```

Export the model in main():

```
QQuickView view;
MyModel theModel;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("theModel", &theModel);
```

Use it as follows in QML:

```
CheckBox {
    onClicked: {
       checked = !checked
       if(checked)
           theModel.editLocale = "nl_NL"
       else
           theModel.editLocale = "en_US"
}
SpinBox { //this is derived from the QtQuick.Controls 2.5 Control type you are looking at
    locale: Qt.locale(theModel.editLocale)
    to: 2000
    value: 1000
}
```

In this example you should see the thousands-separator switch between dot and comma when toggling the checkbox.

***Warning***: this code is not tested as my environment doesn't recognize the `locale` property